# Efficient Algorithm to Find the Closest Points of Two Sets

Tags: convex-analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let's assume there are two sets $R$ and $B$ with each having $n$ points in the plane. Is there an Algorithm with $\Theta(n \log n)$ that can find points $r$ and $b$ with minimal distance such that $r \in R$ and $b \in B$?

Comment: $n$ denotes for what? the size of $R\cup B$ ?

Comment: The number of points in each set.

Comment: http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/mindist.pdf might be a good place to start.

Comment: I do not know how one notation $n$ can denote for two different things $R$, $B$.

Comment: n in this context simply means that both sets are of the size n. There are of equal size.